Is there a way to override packages and versions with pipx install, e.g. psycopg2 -> psycopg2-binary?
Say I need to install some Python project 'foo'.
It has a requirements.txt or setup.py or setup.cfg or pyproject.toml or omgwtf.python that lists psycopg2 as a dependency.
But on my install target I don't have a C toolchain or libpq headers, and it's not particularly feasible to install one, so I want to install foo using psycopg2-binary instead of psycopg2.
Is there any way to do this with pipx install git+https://web.site/foo w/o cloning the sources and locally patching the Python dependencies - which might express this dependency in any of several inscrutable and overlapping forms due to the currently perl-esque TMTOWTDI nature of Python builds and dependency management?
It looks like pipx has --pip-args which can be used to pass --prefer-binary or --only-binary=psycopg2, but this fails as psycopg2 has no binary distribution, instead it's in a different pip package. Is this a legacy packaging style issue with psycopg2:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement psycopg2
ERROR: No matching distribution found for psycopg2

For now I'm working around this by cloning the sources and patching the setup.py, but it's fragile as the patch breaks whenever other dependencies change. A simple sed would work but risks changing things it shouldn't. All in all it's just ugly. There must be a better way?

Use a custom index url, and upload a pre-built psycopg2 wheel to your own index.

"Is there any way to do this … w/o cloning the sources and locally patching the Python dependencies…?" Nope, there is no. "But on my install target I don't have a C toolchain or libpq headers, and it's not particularly feasible to install one…" If have only one target why not just download the corresponding wheel, move it to the target and install with pip install --find-links=/path/to/directory ?

@phd The problem is that a psycopg2-binary wheel would not satisfy a requirement on psycopg2. This is the only project I know of which publishes wheels under a different metadata name, and it's annoying..

@wim "This is the only project I know of which publishes wheels under a different metadata name" Tensorflow and Torch with all variants: CPU, GPU, Tensorflow-aarch64?…

@wim https://pypi.org/project/pysqlite3-binary/
